# Invalid Auth Header Using Run Flow In Another Org From UnofficialSf

Tags: apex, oauth2, authentication

When running the unlocked package [Run Flow In Another Org](https://unofficialsf.com/automate-across-multiple-salesforce-orgs-with-runflowonanotherorg-action/) I see a 400 `Invalid_Auth_Header` error in Debug Logs. Getting a successful response from Postman so I'm guessing something has changed in Salesforce since this class was created using API 51.0 but I can't tell what should be changed. I see 2 others had same issue in past year but no responses on Disqus.

I realize using Named Credentials would be better for the Authentication but that would require refactoring the entire Apex Class and Test which I'm not well qualified to do so want to stay with username and password initially.

```
public with sharing class RunFlowOnAnotherOrg {

    static final String RUN_FLOW_URL = '{0}/services/data/v51.0/actions/custom/flow/{1}';
    static final String GET_TOKEN_URL = '{0}/services/oauth2/token';
    static final String GET_TOKEN_BODY = 'grant_type=password&' +
    'client_id={0}&' +
    'client_secret={1}&' +
    'username={2}&' +
    'password={3}';
    static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = 'error';
    static final String SUCCESS_MESSAGE = 'success';
    static final String POST_METHOD = 'POST';

    @InvocableMethod(label='Run Flow on Another Org' description='Run Flow on Another Org' callout=true configurationEditor='c:runFlowOnAnotherOrgCPE')
    static public List<Response> execute(List<Request> requestList) {
        List<response> responseList = new List<response>();
        for(Request request: requestList) {
            Response resp = new Response();
            if(request.useFutureMethod) {
                launchFuture(JSON.serialize(request));
            } else {
                HTTPResponse res = sendRequest(request);
            
                if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    resp.result = SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
                } else {
                    resp.result = ERROR_MESSAGE;
                }
                
            }
            responseList.add(resp);
            
        }
        return responseList;
    }

    static HttpResponse sendRequest(Request request) {
        System.debug('sending request: ' + JSON.serialize(request));
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(String.format(RUN_FLOW_URL, new List<String> {request.baseOrgURL, request.flowName}));
        req.setMethod(POST_METHOD);
        String accessToken = getAccessToken(request);
        //'Basic client_id=' + request.consumerSecret + '&client_secret=' + request.consumerSecret;
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        String postBody = '';
        if(String.isNotEmpty(request.inputsJSON)) {
            List<InputParam> inputList = (List<InputParam>) JSON.deserialize(request.inputsJSON, List<InputParam>.class);
            Map<String, String> inputMap = new Map<String,String>();

            for (InputParam param : inputList){
                if(String.isNotBlank( param.key)) {
                    inputMap.put(param.key, param.value);
                }                 
            }
            if(inputMap.size() > 0) {
                postBody += '{ "inputs" :  ' + JSON.serialize(new List<Object> {inputMap}) + ' }';
            }
        }
        req.setBody(postBody);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug ('response is: ' + res.getBody());
        return res;
    }

    static String getAccessToken(Request request) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String accessToken = '';
        req.setEndpoint(String.format(GET_TOKEN_URL, new List<String> {request.baseOrgURL}));
        req.setMethod(POST_METHOD);

        req.setBody(String.format(GET_TOKEN_BODY, new List<String>{request.consumerKey, request.consumerSecret, request.username, request.password}));
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String,Object> responseMap = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            accessToken = (String)responseMap.get('access_token');
        }

        return accessToken;
    }
    @future(callout=true)
    private static void launchFuture(String requestJSON) {
        Request request = (Request)JSON.deserialize(requestJSON, Request.class);
        sendRequest(request);
    }
    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Base URL of the org' required=true)
        public String baseOrgURL;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Consumer Key' required=true)
        public String consumerKey;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Consumer Secret' required=true)
        public String consumerSecret;

        @InvocableVariable(label='username' required=true)
        public String username;

        @InvocableVariable(label='password' required=true)
        public String password;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Name of the flow' required=true)
        public String flowName;

        @InvocableVariable
        public Boolean useFutureMethod = false;
        

        @InvocableVariable(label='inputsJSON')
        public String inputsJSON;
    }

    public class Response{
        @InvocableVariable
        public String result;
    }

    private class InputParam{
        private String key;
        private String value;
    }
}
```